# utf8, utf8mb4, utf8_general_ci trouble on PDO retrieving data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8

I've a db stored on a server that is encoded in

> utf8_general_ci

All my pages are forced to be in

> utf8

My connection to the db is like this:

```
return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXX',
            'XXXX', 'XXXX', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8mb4",
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

But I even tried as option
    "SET NAMES utf8"

When I try to parse my resultset I always had a problem with some text field, and if I try command likes:

```
            $originalEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($fieldWithProbs);
```

returns to me

> ASCII

and then if I trying to convert it with commands like:

```
                $newEncodedData = mb_convert_encoding($fieldWithProbs, 'UTF-8');
```

it doesn't seems to works and if I asking again the type of encoding is still in ASCII.
The strange things is that works in local but not on the remote server with same type of encoding on db set.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is a subset of UTF8. If you convert ASCII to UTF8, the binary representation remains the same.

So there is no problem at all, just a little uncomprehension.

[The Minimum Every Software Developer Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/unicode.html)

Comment: ok my little knowledge seems to put me on the wrong path. But my probs is that if i try to `$var=$fieldWithProb` it gives me a NULL

Comment: Two things : mb_convert_encoding() takes three arguments, this could be the culprit. Also, if ( $var = $field ) yields null, then one of the two is null. You have to var_dump to narrow down the problem.

Comment: the third argument is optional `string mb_convert_encoding ( string $str , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )` I've made several var_dump before asking :( and I can't spot the problem of why a field of an array that is correct when its assigned to a var is badly converted to null

Comment: You should show you relevant code. It might help. With the information you give there is too much guessing involved.

Comment: i've a field on the db thats contain the string "Melù" -> on the associative array generated by PDO there is "Melù" (by var_dump check) --> if I try to using mb_convert_encoding() the string si converted to "Mel" if i don't using it it simple assigned a null value to the final var...

Answer (score -1):

I solve the problem using this:

```
            $row=array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
```

on the extracted row before doing anything else.
 I hope that it will be helpful for some one, I lost lot of time around this :)

The problem is not on the assign of the "corrupted text" to a var, but on using `json_encode()` that even with the option `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`  i didn't solve the problem.